# Applying a MaskFormatter to a column in my JTable, but the mask is only used on the first cell I edit in the column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jformattedtextfield, maskformatter

```
////DOB column formats to dd/mm/yy
    TableColumn dobColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
    JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField(df);
    tf.setColumns(8);
    try {
        MaskFormatter dobMask = new MaskFormatter("##/##/##");
        dobMask.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
        dobMask.install(tf);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DisplayStudents.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    dobColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(tf));
```

I've followed a similar process to turn cells in a column into ComboBoxes or CheckBoxes and all cells inside those columns have been set to ComoboBoxes/CheckBoxes, but when I set the cell editor for the DOB column to a JFormattedTextField with a mask, the mask is only applied to the first cell I click on in the column.

EDIT: Here's my SSCCE:

```
public class TableExample extends JFrame {
    public TableExample() {
    add(makeTable());
}

private JTable makeTable() {
    Object[][] tableData = {{"","a","b",""}, {"","c","d",""}};
    String[] columns = {"comboBox column", "column2", "column3", "dobColumn"};
    JTable table = new JTable(tableData, columns);
    ////turn into a combo box
    TableColumn comboColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
    comboBox.addItem("1st");comboBox.addItem("2nd");
    comboColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
    ////DOB column formats to dd/mm/yy
    TableColumn dobColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
    JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField(df);
    tf.setColumns(8);
    try {
        MaskFormatter dobMask = new MaskFormatter("##/##/##");
        dobMask.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
        dobMask.install(tf);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(TableExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    dobColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(tf));

    return table;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new TableExample();
    frame.setSize( 300, 300 );
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}
```

}

Comment: `I've followed a similar process to turn cells in a column into ComboBoxes or CheckBoxes and all cells inside those columns have been set to ComoboBoxes/CheckBoxes,` - agreed that is the way it should work.  Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unsure as to why the Mask is destroyed everytime I click a cell inside the dobColumn. So I decided to implement the tableChange method, to recreate the mask whenever a change occurs in the dobColumn

```
public void tableChanged(TableEvent e) {
    if(e.getColumn() == 3) {    //if column edited was the dobColumn
        System.out.println("Remaking mask");
        JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField();
        try {
             MaskFormatter dobMask = new MaskFormatter("##-##-##");
             dobMask.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
             dobMask.install(tf);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DisplayStudents.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(tf));
    }
}
```